# How does one send a [][]byte in Golang to the browser to be decoded as an image

Tags: javascript, json, web, go, arrays

In my back-end golang web server I have converted and processed a directory of images that i have read in using `os.ReadDir`

These images are stored as a `[][]byte`.  I want to be able to send these images through a GET request to be displayed in the browser using Javascript.

I am having trouble figuring out how to begin the process to send the data from the Golang web server.  The resources I am currently using are the typical net/http package, and Gorilla Mux/Websockets.

Here is some sample code that shows how I am currently doing a get request which return some json.  How can I similarly send a [][]byte array instead of rendering a template or JSON?

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func ViewSample(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    type Sample struct {
        Id        int    `json:"id"`
        Name      string `json:"name"`
        User      string `json:"user
    }

    params := mux.Vars(req)
    sampleId := params["id"]

    sample := Sample{
        Id:        3,
        Name:      "test",
        User:      "testuser" 
    }

    json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(sample)
}
```

Comment: What is the client expecting? An jpeg/png encoded image? An octet-stream? Some binary format representing `[][]byte`?

Comment: On the client-side, I want to turn the `[][]byte` back to pngs

Comment: `[][]byte` has no meaning over a network. What is the actual data format expected by the client? Do you want to just send the raw bytes?

Comment: apologies for being unclear; as you said above it is a jpeg/png encoded image. Each image is represented in the Golang backend as an `[]byte`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your image is stored in a `[]byte`, you can write that directly to the `http.ResponseWriter`

```
func GetImage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    image, err := getImage() // getImage example returns ([]byte, error)
    if err != {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.Write(image)
}
```

There's no way to send multiple images in a single response which is natively understood by clients. One method you could use is to return a json document on the first call, which contains a list of links to fetch each image individually.

Comment: hey JimB, it worked like a charm for a single image, thanks so much.  However, I am trying to send an entire array of images `[][]byte`, and the responseWriter seems to only take a `[]byte` as an argument.  Any advice?

Comment: @shinjin: If you want to send multiple images, you need some way to frame that data which the client understands. HTTP itself already provides a protocol to do this, by making one request per image.